# Customized Installation in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to control the package installation process
in Android?

The problem is that I'm asked to install and uninstall packages
without using the default android installer.
I need to control the entire process within my application.

I already have my application in the /system/app/ folder,
so it might have the INSTALL_PACKAGE and DELETE_PACKAGES permission
(that was what I read).

I also have been looking to the source code of the installer,
but can't find a way to start installing or uninstalling
a package on my own.

Could this be done?

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that I'm asked to
>   install and uninstall packages without
>   using the default android installer. I
>   need to control the entire process
>   within my application.

That is not possible from the SDK. You are welcome to write your own firmware that accomplishes this and install it on your own phones.